# Why is the webserver not available in the LAN if I start the server by a service-deamon?

Tags: ubuntu, services, hosts

I have a Laravel application, if I start this application in the CLI with `artisan serve --port=8081 --host=monitoring` it is available in the network with `monitoring:8081`. I create a ServiceDaemon an this daemon start the service after the server has already started. But the domain `monitoring:8081` is not available, only if I enter the ip of ther server ( 127.0.0.1:8081 ) i reach the page.

```
laravel_monitoring.service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/laravel_monitoring.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2024-01-22 11:19:48 CET; 16s ago
   Main PID: 3564 (php)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 9197)
     Memory: 35.7M
        CPU: 179ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/laravel_monitoring.service
             ├─3564 php /var/www/monitoring/artisan serve --port=8081 --host=wohnzimmer
             └─3567 /usr/bin/php8.3 -S wohnzimmer:8081 /var/www/monitoring/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/../resources/server.php

Jän 22 11:19:48 wohnzimmer systemd[1]: Started laravel_monitoring.service.
Jän 22 11:19:49 wohnzimmer artisan[3564]:    INFO  Server running on [http://wohnzimmer:8081].
Jän 22 11:19:49 wohnzimmer artisan[3564]:   Press Ctrl+C to stop the server
```

Comment: See the various solution in [this post](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/cant-access-local-laravel-site-through-laravelapp-domain-only-localhost8000-vagranthomestead). Let me know if one of them works for you.